# How to make images visible in the background by click

Tags: jquery, image, background

I'm new to Javascript & jQuery and trying to make a testsite just to see what can be done by using javascript.

I have a problem.

I have 8 images at the bottom of the page. When you click on the image, i want to let the DIV Gallery show the selected image, and the image will appear in the background of the page. When you click another image, then that image will be show in the DIV Gallery and Background.

**HTML ' Gallery '**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="(URL Img 1)"><img src="(URL Img 1)" alt="Photo 1" /></a>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="(URL Img 2)"><img src="(URL Img 2)" alt="Photo 2" /></a>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="(URL Img 3)"><img src="(URL Img 3)" alt="Photo 3" /></a>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="(URL Img 4)"><img src="(URL Img 4)" alt="Photo 4" /></a>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="(URL Img 5)"><img src="(URL Img 5)" alt="Photo 5" /></a>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="(URL Img 6)"><img src="(URL Img 6)" alt="Photo 6" /></a>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="(URL Img 7)"><img src="(URL Img 7)" alt="Photo 7"/></a>    
        </li>
        <li><a href="(URL Img 8)"><img src="(URL Img 8)" alt="Photo 8" /></a>    
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**HTML Background Image**

```
<div class="background-container" style="background-image:url('(URL Img 1');"></div>
```

**jQuery**

I tried something with this:

```
$("li.selected").on("click", change);

});
```

But it didn't seem to work, or even getting close.
Does anyone know the missing link?

Thankyou very much.
- Yahitchu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gallery a").on("click", function(){
        $('.background-container').css('background-image',url(this.attr("href"));
    }); 
});
```

If the images' url are the same, you could also remove the `<a>` mark and play only with `<img>` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gallery img").on("click", function(){
        $('.background-container').css('background-image',url(this.attr("src"));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't seem to work, it opens the image in a new tabblad, and won't change the background container & gallery.

Comment: Oups, I have used the wrong function `attr` instead of `css`... Code updated. Try this new version

Comment: @KevinMeijvis, code is working. I am not sure about your html/css - because, gallery div contains just one list, so i am not sure WHERE you want to show image, actually, inside this div?

Comment: Hmmm... It still does nothing to my script, you think it's a problem in the html?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting an element doesn't change its class attribute, so `$("li.selected")` will always refer to the first element in the list. Even if this wasn't the case, the selector is (presumably) evaluated when the page is loaded, not when the user clicks; and so even if you changed it to use the selected element, it would still use the first one. It's only the `change` function itself that runs when the user clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You want like this? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/wTt8Z/1/

```
$('#gallery a').on('click',function(){
    var url = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.background-container').css("background-image", "url("+url+")");
});
```

Comment: Yes! But I don't know how to script it!

Comment: you can based on this jsfiddle, html, css and js are all there.